# How to make a bot react to its own message?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make the bot react to it's own message, for a polls feature of my discord server, and I am wondering how to make the bot add reactions to it's message? (Currently, it adds the reaction to the person who executed the .suggestion command.)

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('.suggestion')) {

        const channel = message.guild.channels.find('name', 'polls');
        const args = message.content.slice(12).trim().split(/ +/g);
        let suggestion = args.slice(0).join(" ");
        if (!channel) return;

        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("#55FFFF")
        .setDescription('▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬**«    Vexil Player Suggestion    »**▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\n\n**Suggested By »** ' + message.author + '\n\n**Suggestion »** ' + suggestion + '\n\n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬**«**     @everyone     **»**▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬')
        .setFooter('Vexil', client.user.avatarURL)

    channel.send(embed);
    message.react("")
    message.react("");

  }
});
```

Thank you in advanced for your help and time. <3

Answer (score 8):

You can react directly after the message is sent by using `.then()`

```
channel.send(embed).then(sentEmbed => {
    sentEmbed.react("")
    sentEmbed.react("")
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it still just adds the reaction to the command sender's message?

Comment: @Askingg - please show us your new code with Nik's suggestions. I have used Nik's code (almost exactly) before and it works for me.

Comment: Sure thing @BlunderingPhilosopher. I'll have to put it in a pastebin though, because it's too large to send in a message. I got it working in the end. :)

[Code in Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8KxnuEej)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy!

```
channel.send(embedName).then(sentMessage => {
  const emoji = message.guild.find('name', 'emojiName');
  sentMessage.react(emoji);
});
```

Comment: A broad search of the `guild` object is excessive, but also does not work.

Comment: FYI in v12.x.x and up, this wont work AT ALL. Use caching

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions in [How Find Emojis By Name In Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074768/how-find-emojis-by-name-in-discord-js) and personal testing, using

```
channel.send(embed).then(function(message) {
    message.react(message.guild.emojis.find('name', "emojiName"))
});
```

will send your message and then react with the find result of `emojiName` (be as specific as possible)