# How Find Emojis By Name In Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So I have been utterly frustrated these past few days because I have not been able to find a single resource online which properly documents how to find emojis when writing a discord bot in javascript. I have been referring to this guide whose documentation about emojis seems to be either wrong, or outdated:

https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/using-emojis

What I need is simple; to just be able to reference an emoji using the `.find()` function and store it in a variable. Here is my current code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const fs = require("fs");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const guild = new Discord.Guild();
const bean = client.emojis.find("name", "bean");

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (bean) {
      if (!message.content.startsWith("@")){
        if (message.channel.name == "bean" || message.channel.id == "478206289961418756") {
            if (message.content.startsWith("<:bean:" + bean.id + ">")) {
                message.react(bean.id);
            }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      console.error("Error: Unable to find bean emoji");
    }
});
```

*p.s. the whole bean thing is just a test*

But every time I run this code it just returns this error and dies:

**`(node:3084) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead`**

Is there anything I missed? I am so stumped...

Comment: from the warning I'd say you need to do something like `client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "bean")`. I never used discord.js so I may be completely wrong

Comment: @jonatjano So I tried what you wrote there and the error seems to be gone but it's still dying : /

Comment: you may need to have it set in your event, I don't think these collection are dynamics, meaning the `bean` var doesn't get the new values as they come but keep the initials values only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never used `discord.js` so I may be completely wrong

from the warning I'd say you need to do something like

```
client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "bean")
```

Plus after looking at the [`Discord.js Doc`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) it seems to be the way to go. BUT the docs never say anything about `client.emojis.find("name", "bean")` being wrong

Comment: Alright so I have used a combination of code from both answers and it has finally worked but it appears that you can't award correct answers to 2 people at the same time. But I awarded it to you since you helped me fix the initial error

Comment: just in case someone pass later and new answers are added: the other answer OP speak of is [@BaderH.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075214/10153945)

Answer (score 2):

I've made changes to your code.

I hope it'll help you!

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('ready');
});


client.on('message', message => {
 var bean = message.guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name == 'bean');
 // By guild id 
 if(message.guild.id == 'your guild id') {
 if(bean) {
      if(message.content.startsWith("<:bean:" + bean.id + ">")) {
       message.react(bean.id);
      }
     }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the [switching to v12 discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start)

> v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use collection methods such as `Collection#get` on data structures like `Client#users`. You will now have to directly ask for cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods. Any method that is called directly on a manager will call the API, such as `GuildMemberManager#fetch` and `MessageManager#delete`.

In this specific situation, you need to add the cache object to your expression:

```js
var bean = message.guild.emojis.cache?.find(emoji => emoji.name == 'bean');
```

Comment: i have an issue with that since intents happened. sometimes the find function retrieve undefined on cache.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone like me finds this while looking for an answer, in v12 you will have to add cache in, making it look like this:

```
var bean = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name == 'bean');
```

rather than:

`var bean = message.guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name == 'bean');`